# Jquery hide / show not working in ie and safari

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, safari, hide, show

i am using the following function to control some select options.
it works great in ff and chrome, but not in ie and safari.

```
$( "#option_{/literal}{$product.product_id}{literal}_1251" ).change(function()  { //sp
    if(4272 == $(this).val()){

    $("#option_{/literal}{$product.product_id}{literal}_1251 option[value='4350']").hide();
    $("#option_{/literal}{$product.product_id}{literal}_1253").prop('selectedIndex',2);
    $("#option_{/literal}{$product.product_id}{literal}_1255").prop( "checked", false );
    $("#option_{/literal}{$product.product_id}{literal}_1253 option[value='4357']").hide();
    $("#option_{/literal}{$product.product_id}{literal}_1253 option[value='4330']").hide();
    $("#option_{/literal}{$product.product_id}{literal}_1253 option[value='4282']").hide();
    $("#option_{/literal}{$product.product_id}{literal}_1253 option[value='4283']").hide();
    $("#option_{/literal}{$product.product_id}{literal}_1253 option[value='4284']").hide();
    $("#option_{/literal}{$product.product_id}{literal}_1253 option[value='4285']").hide();
    $("#option_{/literal}{$product.product_id}{literal}_1253 option[value='4286']").hide();
    $("#option_{/literal}{$product.product_id}{literal}_1253 option[value='4287']").hide();
    $("#option_{/literal}{$product.product_id}{literal}_1253 option[value='4288']").hide();
    $("#option_{/literal}{$product.product_id}{literal}_1253 option[value='4330']").show();
    $("#option_{/literal}{$product.product_id}{literal}_1253 option[value='4282']").show();
    $("#option_{/literal}{$product.product_id}{literal}_1255").hide();

    }
});
```

Is there a way to make this function work in the other browsers too?
Any ideas?

Comment: OMG really? what is that? An ID?

Comment: is there any console error?

Comment: yes it is an id, no errors

Comment: no, that doesn't solve it

Comment: then its better to create a fiddle for this.

Comment: i guess its an ie and safari issue that keeps hide and show from working in select. using remove() and append does the trick

Answer (score 0):

I've been hunting around for answers to a similar problem. We have a large dynamic form, that shows/hides the pages as you click through it. In Chrome and FF, it works like a charm using a hideAll on all the pages first, then show() for the active pages.

Unfortunately it doesn't work in IE (10, 11/edge) or Safari. IE throws a few strange 500 errors (that might relate more to our Wakanda system we're using), but safari doesn't show anything in the console - it just seems to be ignoring the show call.

I might have a shot at using remove() and append(), though it might be better for me to add/remove a class that has display:none and display:block. This might be a solution for you as well.

Cheers

EDIT:  Just realised that you can't display:none an option in a select list.... So apologies for wasting your time :P